# Typical 3G data session management

Tags: mobile

I am trying to understand what constitutes a new data session as listed in a CDR, where the packet switching core is a typical Nokia Siemens setup.

Firstly, are data sessions managed between a phone's OS and a Serving GPRS Support Node (SGSN)? If this is the case then does moving to a new cell served by a different SGSN create a new session in a CDR or does the handoff maintain the same session?

Also does anyone have a link to a good explanation of how Android handles data sessions in detail?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Difficult to tell because it depends on the CDR, but in general, a data session in a mobile network refers to a "PDP context". A PDP context is the state kept for a user in the SGSN and GGSN (in a 3G network) and down to the UA (your phone) via RNCs and the NodeBs ("base stations"). The actual protocol used between GGSN and SGSN is a GTP tunnel while from the SGSN to RNCs you have an interface called IuPS.

PDP context typically contains start and end time as well as how many packets and bytes that have been transferred and it is likely this is the information you are seeing in the CDR. There's a bunch of other data in there as well.

When you roam from one NodeB to another your PDP context will remain the same in SGSN. A "smallish" network might have two SGSNs (for redundancy purposes), typically multiple RNCs (10-100) while there are thousands of NodeBs. If you roam within the area of one RNC, the RNC will handle the roaming part and inform other nodes of the move. Note how the GTP tunnel doesn't need to change though as it remains from the SGSN to the same RNC. If you roam between two NodeBs that are connected to different RNCs, the SGSN will be involved as well.

To further complicate things, there is something called 3GDT which stands for Direct Tunneling. This means the GTP tunnel will be directly from the NodeB to the GGSN as to offload traffic from the SGSN. If 3GDT is used, the GGSN will naturally be involved in inter-RNC roaming as well.

Your PDP context is only terminated if you shutdown your phone, loose reception or something goes wrong in the mobile network, so PDP contexts can easily last for days or weeks. Sometimes however, CDRs are chopped up into smaller pieces, despite the PDP context is still active. This is to make it easier to see in the CDR that the user is active, otherwise you might not get any billing data for a subscriber until the PDP context is terminated and since it can potentially live for eternity, that would make billing difficult.

Android is not really involved in this. The OS on your phone only serves to give the baseband chip in your phone some configuration data, like which APN to use and so forth. The rest is handled by the baseband chip, built by suppliers like QualComm. Many chips are used throughout different handsets from different phone producers with different operating systems so compatibility on this layer is really between the baseband chip and the mobile network and not up to the operating system on the handset.

Also see:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_Network_Controller
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPRS_core_network

Comment: Excellent response, answered all my questions and some others I wanted to know but didn't ask. For what it is worth the network in question does cut off sessions in the CDR at 24hrs. I am just now wondering about baseband chips, do they typically have timeouts for which they end PDP contexts, if there is no activity for a given amount of time? Similarly does a successful wifi connection, or switching between 3G and 4G cause a PDP context to end? I am trying to read up on these given the great information you have given me, but any addition points would be awesome (if you have time).

Comment: As far as I know, baseband chips do not have a timeout, perhaps it is configurable but I wouldn't see a point in doing that. Roaming between 3G and 4G typically doesn't end your PDP context as most modern PGWs/GGSNs are actually the same box, just supporting different signalling and protocols. Going to WiFi on the other hand might very well tear down your PDP context. It could be placed in an idle state - not sure what is the most common, but should be fairly easy to find out (check if you have an IP on your phone from mobile network, go to WiFi, do you still have your IP from mobile or not?)